# Endeca 11.1 on win 10 installation

Tags: endeca

Endeca Toools and Framework 11.1 is not installing completly in win 10 any ideas?
In the progress bar it is showing 100% but the installation is not even completed for hours, any one come across this situation, please help.

Comment: Are you installing this as the `Administrator`?

Comment: Hi radimpe, Yes, ofcourse, I am the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced a similar issue while installing Endeca 11.3 on Windows 2012 R2. The installer runs to 100% and then stops in the process of 'Save Inventory Pending'.

Quit the installer, then made sure I execute the 'setup.exe' as `Administrator`. First 'deinstall' the last attempt and then installed again without issue.

Suspect your problem is not running the installer as `Administrator` (even though you are an admin on the machine).